# How to find the object containing the highest value in an array

Tags: javascript

I'm using a library that predicts the emotion of the user in front of the webcam. There are four emotions: angry, sad, surprised and happy. I want to check which emotion has the highest score. When i console.log predictedEmotions I see this:

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
 0: {emotion: "angry"value: 0.08495773461377512}
 1: {emotion: "sad", value: 0.05993173506165729}
 2: {emotion: "surprised", value: 0.054032595527500206}
 3: {emotion: "happy", value: 0.18562819815754616}
```

Any ideas on how to get the emotion with the highest value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could reduce the array and take the object with the highest value. Then take take the emotion of the object.

```js
var data = [{ emotion: "angry", value: 0.08495773461377512 }, { emotion: "sad", value: 0.05993173506165729 }, { emotion: "surprised", value: 0.054032595527500206 }, { emotion: "happy", value: 0.18562819815754616 }],
    highest = data
        .reduce((a, b) => a.value > b.value ? a : b)
        .emotion;
    
console.log(highest);
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you very much! I will mark it as answer when I can.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use reduce

```js
const highest = arr.reduce((a, b) => a.value > b.value ? a : b, {});
console.log(highest);
```

```html
<script>
const arr = [
    {
        emotion: "angry",
        value: 0.08495773461377512
    },
    {
        emotion: "sad",
        value: 0.05993173506165729
    },
    {
        emotion: "surprised",
        value: 0.054032595527500206
    },
    {
        emotion: "happy",
        value: 0.18562819815754616
    }
];
</script>
```

Or you could use sort (but I'd prefer reduce because of performance)

```js
arr.sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value);
console.log(arr[0]);
```

```html
<script>
    const arr = [
        {
            emotion: "angry",
            value: 0.08495773461377512
        },
        {
            emotion: "sad",
            value: 0.05993173506165729
        },
        {
            emotion: "surprised",
            value: 0.054032595527500206
        },
        {
            emotion: "happy",
            value: 0.18562819815754616
        }
    ];
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [
            {emotion: "angry", value: 0.08495773461377512},
            {emotion: "sad", value: 0.05993173506165729},
            {emotion: "surprised", value: 0.054032595527500206},
            {emotion: "happy", value: 0.18562819815754616}
        ],
        highest = process(data);

    function process(data) {
        return data.sort(function (a, b) {
            return b.value - a.value;
        });
    }

    console.log("highest==>",highest,"sorted-array ==>",data[0].emotion);
```